# How to pull images from directory without server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have one image slider webpage. In that many image tags are there. So whenever i want to add image in slider, every time i am adding  tags in html. Is it possible to do without adding image tag.

```
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">


   <img src="images/1.jpeg" width="620" height="320" />
   <img src="images/2.jpeg" width="620" height="320" />
   <img src="images/3.jpeg" width="620" height="320" />
   <img src="images/4.jpeg" width="620" height="320" />

</div>
```

If i want to add new image, i have to add new img tag.Is it possible to add images without without `<img>` in the html??

I have tried with jquery. there i am not getting images from the folder.

```
  $('<img />')
    .attr('src', 'images/')
    .appendTo('#div3')
```

How we can solve this problem ?

Comment: share the code of your javascript attempt...

Comment: Is there a good reason that you don't want to add new `img` tags? You know you can do it dynamically by JS right?

Comment: @RakeshShetty the link which is there it will deals with only activex obect which is not supported in linux platforms

Comment: @TJ :I have shared jquery cod in question

Comment: @LcSalazar yes but how we can fetch images from directory in js

Comment: If the folder is in the server, only a "server-side" language will do it... @rjdmello 's answer may work, but require some security adjustments on the server...

Comment: @LcSalazar I am using in client side only

Answer (score 1):

i think its all ready done in [Is there a way to return a list of all the image file names from a folder using only Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using)

```
$.ajax({
 url: "http://yoursite.com/images/",
  success: function(data){
    $(data).find("td > a").each(function(){
       // will loop through 
       alert("Found a file: " + $(this).attr("href"));
   });
 }
 });
```

Comment: I am not using any server.Only html,js,jquery

Comment: where do you save image give that path in url

Comment: i used and not displaying anything .file path is file:///home/indiapc_dev_new1/my_project/jeevan%28image_slider%29/images/

Comment: relativ path is not working. how it will take relative path if server is not there..i gave url: "file://images/", url= "images/"...both r not working

Comment: if you have mainFolder/ in that you have your code in mainfolder/yourcode.js and image folder as mainfolder/images then give path as "images/ " or "../images" try with this

Answer (score 0):

**Utilizing the jQuery library.**

You can use the following:

```
$("#slideshow").append("<img src=\"images/5.jpeg\" />")
```

Or the following (better readability)

```
var newImg = $("<img />").attr("src","images/5.jpeg").css({"width":"620px","height":"320px"})
$("#slideshow").append(newImg);
```

Now to retrieve a file listing of the images in your directory dynamically you will need some sort of server side language (php, ruby, python, c#, nodejs, etc) as Javascript cannot access the file system of the server. Without a server side language you could look into create a JSON or XML file that is then read by your Javascript so that you are not changing html but adding new items quickly.

```
{"images": [
  {"src" : "images/5.jpeg",
   "css": {
         "width" : "620px",
         "height" : "320px"
    }
  }, {
   "src" : "images/6.jpeg",
   "css": {
         "width" : "620px",
         "height" : "320px"
  }
]}
```

Then do something like the following to retrieve the json file you created:

```
$.getJSON("images.json",function(data){
  $.each(data,function(i,image){
    var newImg = $("<img />").attr("src",image.src).css(image.css);
    $("#slideshow").append(newImg);
  });
});
```

This is untested code and could use a few tweaks to get working.

**Resources** to take a look at as well to get more information.

stackoverflow: [jquery loop on Json data using $.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342371/jquery-loop-on-json-data-using-each)

jquery-api: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/