# Preload images dynamically from directory with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating an JPEG image sequence in JS. Now, I'm trying to create a function that will preload the images from the directory `assets/img/frames/...`

Is there a way I can load everything from within the directory into an array and loop through it to check whether the image is loaded or not?
I'm trying to avoid writing each individual file into the array since there are 500+ images.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preloading images with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Comment: You cannot list local files in js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using
and for preloading images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: The (first) link posted by @A.Rama combined with this: [How to load all the images from one of my folder into my web page, using Jquery/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18480589/4728655) - might do the trick.

Comment: Interesing, that's a nice trick to read the directory content without needing a backend script.