# Allow listing of subdirectory on firebase

Tags: .htaccess, firebase

I'd like to allow the listing of a subdirectory on firebase, however I cannot find any file to edit this for at: https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html

I have directory `/images` that contains more than a 100 pictures, and there can be added more later, so I want to be able to use an `ajax` request to list the contents and then use that as a `JSON` object.
That last part should be no problem ([Is there a way to return a list of all the image file names from a folder using only Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using))

But firebase by default always returns a `404` when trying to go to any subfolder.

I've tried with `.htaccess` things like:

```
Options +Indexes
```

or

```
IndexIgnore *
```

But firebase seems to ignore `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Hosting does not have an option to list directory contents. You can include an index.html that contains the files, which gives the same result.