# How to Display Images sequentially from a folder using HTML-Javascript-CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, image, directory, sequential

- There are few images stored in a folder with random names.
- The    contents of the folder will constantly be changing but they
  will have    only images and no other kind of documents.
- Therefore i cannot predefine the image names in src.
- I want to display the images sequentially (one after another with
  specific time interval) using HTML-Javascript-CSS codes.
- The folder is on the client side only.
- Or atleast i should be able to read the filenames in the folder.

  I cannot use PHP. How do i do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: BTW: This has been asked [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994212/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-list-of-all-the-image-file-names-from-a-folder-using) [than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087502/foreach-file-in-directory-jquery) [once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031951/getting-images-from-folder-with-for-jquery-slideshow).

Comment: If you know your users will be using IE and you're willing to compromise in many other ways (including user acceptance) then I think HTML Applications (.hta) are allowed local filesystem access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not trivially possible for security reasons. No webpage (even locally) is allowed to simply read your folder content. There have been some workarounds for some browsers, but I don't think there is a true Cross-Browser solution.

That said, there is the HTML5 [file API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) that allows the user to select the images or drag and drop them to a local website.

Another option would be to have a small executable file that creates for instance a json List of your files and have the website read the filenames from there.

After you have the filenames, use any HTML/JS/CSS gallery.